# How to adjust bootstrap to make it more responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm creating a website and I'm having trouble making it responsive, specifically the navbar. After I resize the window it just "collapses" but not in a way that I've intended.

[image: Screenshot of navbar collapsing]

As you can see the navbar is messed up. I need help with adjusting it correctly.
This also occurs after I resize it to "mobile-size" as you can see:

[image: Screenshot of mobile view]

It looks really ugly. The "header" part is messed up and there is a big empty space between the navbar and the "home" picture (the eye). I would really appreciate any help. Here is a "fiddle" with code. https://jsfiddle.net/k968gLa5/

```
.row-fluid .span4>a {
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #ced0d2;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Some code otherwise it won't let me post this :P

Comment: Why are you using Bootstrap 2.x classes with Bootstrap 3?

Comment: The problem is your css code, try to remove some spacing, padding and font size in your menu.

Comment: im new to bootstrap so that's why :P what classes did you mean?